# Profile mex function in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, mex

In [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) it is explained how to profile an .exe file in visual studio. Is there any way to profile a mex code using the same procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You sure can. Just enable generation of debug info (symbols) when building the MEX file, and attach to MATLAB.exe from the Analyze->Profile menu in Visual Studio.

It's nearly the same procedure as for debugging MEX files with Visual Studio. The process is trivial if you built the MEX file with a VS project (rather than the `mex` command), in which case you simply enable Profiling information in the project (Linker-Advanced-Profile property), build, and then attach to MATLAB.exe from the Analyze->Profiler->Attach/detach... menu item.

If you are building with [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) from MATLAB, you need to enable building a MEX file with symbolic information, but also enable optimization:

```
mex -g -O -largeArrayDims myMEX.cpp
```

I generally build MEX files from VS projects rather than with `mex`, so I can't say how well this latter option works, but the documentation for the [`-O` switch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#f24432) suggests that you can have optimization and symbolic information generation at the same time. **EDIT**: It may also require editing your mexopts.bat and adding `/DEBUG /PROFILE` (does not disable compiler optimizations!) to `LINKFLAGS`. This may also allow you to omit `-g` from `mex`, but I can't say.

**EDIT 2**: From R2014a, MEX options are no longer managed with .bat files. Instead, look for an XML file like `C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014a\mex_C_win64.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the response is really appreciated! `Generate Debug Info: Yes(\Debug)`, `Profile: Yes(PROFILE)` and then matlab is attached. A new tad appeared in the VS2010 with the message `Currently profiling` but is loading without end. Am I doing something wrong? PS: I have run the mex function during profiling.

Comment: @Thoth That is correct, it is profiling when it has the perpetually rotating swirly thing.  You need to detach to have VS report the results. Use the Performance Explorer (usually a tab on the left) to detach, or from the Analyze->Profiler menu. Sometimes _stopping_ instead of detaching can crash MATLAB.

Comment: Do we have to run the mex function on the background, via matlab, while VS is profiling?

Comment: @Thoth Yes, profiling essentially watches it run and looks at how frequently individual lines are observed executing. Stop profiling, make a new profiling session, attach, go to MATLAB and start the MEX file running, then when it's done go back to VS and detach.

Comment: @chappjc What about MEX files not built from either VS or using the ```mex``` tool in MATLAB? What about ones compiled from an object file using g++ with -lmex and -lmx? When I attempted it, VS would hang forever when trying to analyze it.